# How to force download file with Spring controller?

Tags: spring, browser, download

i have a string controller to download a xml file but the download window is open everytime..

this is the code of my controller :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void export(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws JsonGenerationException,
        JsonMappingException, IOException, DatatypeConfigurationException {
    byte[] bytes  = service.exportXML(getUsername());
    String xmlFileName = "filename.xml";
     response.setContentType("application/force-download");
     response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(bytes.length));
     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+xmlFileName);

     response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
}
```

What i can do to browser never open download window and save the file immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible from server side. Due to securtity reasons browser will not allow to auto download the files if specified in the browser itself.

For example, if you want to auto download and open a docx file type in your browser. Then check this link [How can I open these .docx files from Chrome more quickly](https://askubuntu.com/a/288878)

Hope you will understand the limitation here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
```

Comment: Does this really change browser behavior to save the file automatically? Wouldn't it be browser and user preference dependent?

Answer (score 0):

Well i have earlier tried for txt files which opened directly. Nw they get saved instead of opening.